# jQuery, setting an active class based on the data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After extensive research, I've come up with nothing that works perfectly.

My HTML

```
<div class="option" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-name="Home" data-url="/" title="Home">
    <p class="select-button"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
```

My JS

```
$(function(){
    activeClass();
});

function activeClass(){
    //define the page url
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    //decode the uri
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    //find each item containing .option as a class
    $(".option").each(function() {
        //store the data of these in a variable
        var ref = $(this).data("url"); 
        if(path.substring(0,ref.length) == ref){
            //set the closest one to active
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    })  
}
```

The JS does work but it also makes the home button have the active class when on a page with `/` in the URL but not on the homepage.

The aim of it is for the webpage to detect or determine the button that matches the URL of the page. For instance, the homepage would match with the button code I have provided or /auth/login would match with the login button.

Comment: instead of `path.substring(0,ref.length) == ref` try using `path.indexOf(ref) !== -1`;

Comment: That seems to be returning the same thing

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(path, ref);` after the line `var ref = $(this).data("url");` ?

Comment: On the home page

    /
    /authentication/login/index.php
    /content/register/index.php

On the login page (where login and home are marked active)

    /authentication/login/index.php /
    /authentication/login/index.php /authentication/login/index.php
    /authentication/login/index.php /content/register/index.php

Comment: Sorry about the messy comment. I can't figure out how to format it

Comment: What values are you using in `data-url` (other than "/") and what are the paths you are navigating on?

Comment: so / is the home /auth/login/index.php is for the login page etc

Comment: @BenjaminMills using `/` is not a good idea because it will match all urls

Comment: Then how do I get the home button so go to the homepage without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end this boils down to string comparison. If you compare these strings based on their beginnings, you can find yourself in trouble if two or more routes start with the same sequence of characters, but one is shorter than the other. This is very much the case with "/" being the home url, and also the very first character of every other urls.

In case you don't expect such “conflicting” urls (other than "/") among in your `.option`s, then you could create a simple exception with the home url, as you can see in the example below.

```
$(function () {
    // Immediate function
    !function () {
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        // Changed regex to not replace single "/"
        path = path.replace(/.+\/$/, "");
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);

        // Exception if path is "/"
        if (path === '/') {
            $('[data-url="/"]').addClass('active');
            return;
        }

        // Check all `.options` but not `[data-url="/"]`
        $('[data-url]:not([data-url="/"])').each(function() {
            var ref = $(this).data('url');

            if (path.indexOf(ref) === 0) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        })  
    }()
});
```